Is a surjective immersion a submersion?
I was trying to prove that a surjective isometry between two Riemannian manifolds, say $f:(M, g)\rightarrow (N, h)$, is a local diffeomorphism.
I realize that isometry should be an immersion at least, so I want to prove that $df: T_pM\rightarrow T_{f(p)}N$ is an isomorphism between these two vector spaces, but it is hard for me to find a vector in $v\in T_pM$ that corresponds to $df(v)$.
My hunch is that the pushforward of a surjective immersion $df: TM\rightarrow TN$ is surjective, is it this correct, or is my work just in vain?

Do you already know Sard's Theorem?

Ah, I merely heard of it but never used it

This theorem should be a part of your toolbox if you want to study differential geometry.

Yeah, you're absolutely right. I see the proof below, that's neat.

The answer is yes, any surjective immersion between smooth manifolds is a submersion.
Proof. Let $f : M \to N$ be a surjective immersion between smooth manifolds. If $N$ is empty, then $M$ is empty as well and thus $f$ is a submersion. Otherwise, by Sard's theorem, pick a regular value $y \in N$ of $f$. Since $f$ is surjective, pick some $x \in M$ such that $f(x) = y$. Then since $y$ is a regular value of $f$, we have that $df_x$ is surjective, and since $f$ is an immersion, we have that $df_x$ is injective. Thus, $df_x$ is an isomorphism, and so $\dim M = \dim N$.
Now the fact that $f$ is an immersion tells us that $df_x$ is surjective for all $x \in M$, i.e. $f$ is a submersion. $\square$
